# Solve: line and rectangle intersections

Tags: equation-solving, regions, computational-geometry, geometry

I have been trying to find the intersections between a rectangle and a line, following the example given in the Solve function:

```
Solve[{x, y} ∈ Line[{{-1, 0}, {2, 1}}] && {x, y} ∈ 
   Circle[], {x, y}]
Graphics[{{Blue, Line[{{-1, 0}, {2, 1}}], 
   Circle[]}, {PointSize[Large], Red, Point[{x, y}] /. %}}]
```

this code works well of course, finding both intersections between the circle and the line. However, if I try to substitute the circle with a rectangle the code stops working:

```
lin := Line[{{-2, -3}, {2, 1}}]
rec := Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]
Solve[{x, y} ∈ lin && {x, y} ∈ rec, {x, y}]
Graphics[{{Red, lin, Blue, rec}, {PointSize[Large], Yellow, 
   Point[{x, y}] /. %}}]
```

Any idea of how to make it work?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle) has dimension 2, so the intersection of `lin` and `rec`is a line and not 2 points. You can fix this by taking the boundary of the [`Rectangle`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Rectangle) instead:

```
lin = Line[{{-2, -3}, {2, 1}}]
rec = RegionBoundary @ Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]
Solve[{x, y} ∈ lin && {x, y} ∈ rec, {x, y}]
Graphics[{
    {Red, lin, Blue, rec},
    {PointSize[Large], Yellow, Point[{x, y}] /. %}
}]
```

> Line[{{-2, -3}, {2, 1}}]
>
> Line[{{-1, -1}, {1, -1}, {1, 1}, {-1, 1}, {-1, -1}}]
>
> {{x -> 0, y -> -1}, {x -> 1, y -> 0}}
>
> [image]

You could also just use [`RegionIntersection`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionIntersection) instead:

```
Graphics[{Red, lin, Blue, rec, PointSize[Large], Yellow, RegionIntersection[lin, rec]}]
```

> [image]

Comment: thanks, I was about to write that I solved the issue using a polyline instead of a rectangle. Your solution seems much simpler in practice though.
I have been trying to implement your code, but for some reason the RegionBoundary function seems not to work (it remains blue in the code).
It looks like the built-in function is read as a variable with no value assigned... I am perplexed

Comment: @saimon RegionBoundary was introduced in M10, so you must be using an earlier version. In that case, you need to convert the Rectangle to a polyline yourself